# How to add a margin or padding to a Snackbar?

Tags: flutter, material-design, snackbar

I have been working on the Snackbar and achieved in my project successfully. However, there is this little thing which I want to add to Snackbar and that is the `margins`. I have seen in this link : [Snackbars - Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#anatomy)

I really want my Snackbar to come like this :

[image: Target Picture]

What I'm getting is this now :

[image: Resultant Picture]

My code is :

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text("Feild(s) are empty!"),
    duration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  );
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Comment: This is something that should be done in flutter instead. Flutter seem to use an old version of the specs of the snack-bar

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Flutter team have updated the snackbar to match the material design in this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/31275). You can simply get the new behavior by setting

> behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating

Here is a sample code

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  elevation: 6.0,
  backgroundColor: Configs.current.COLORS_PRIMARY,
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
  content: Text(
    "Snack bar test",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
);
```

and the result will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Not sure about margins. Round corner SnackBar can be created like:

```
Scaffold
    .of(context)
    .showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            content: Text(message),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)))));
```

Use required border radius in above.

**Update**:
You can use floating `SnackBar` to add default margins. Pass below to `SnackBar` constructor:

```
Scaffold
.of(context)
.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)))));
```

Comment: This is great and works perfect for me. E.g. https://imgur.com/a/O9Nrcdq

Comment: I want to add border outside of snackbaraction label. is there any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: How can we add 2 pixels border on snackbar? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Minimal code:**

```
var snackbar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Hello World!'),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
);
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
```

---

**Full code:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            var snackbar = SnackBar(
              content: Text('Hello World!'),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            );
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
          },
          child: Text('Show SnackBar'),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: How can we add 2 pixels border on snackbar? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Not possible as of today, unless you either make changes in the source code or create something using Overlay or other widgets on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This answer is outdated and should only be viewed for historical reasons. Choose an appropriate solution from above

---

Sadly I haven't found any options or possibilities, given by Flutter, to implement a round `SnackBar`.

If you really need/want the rounded corners and spacing you can copy the source code of the `SnackBar` and make your adjustments to the copy. Remember to add `implements SnackBar` to your class definition.

I've started the implementation and added the rounded corners. You'll just have to add the bottom padding for Phones like the iPhone X, which have elements at the bottom, obscuring the view. (To get the bottom spacing you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`.)

---

*Standalone example you can copy:*

[image: Demo]

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_app_name/my_snack.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyBody()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(MySnack(content: Text('MySnack!')));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**my_snack.dart**

````
// Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const double _kSnackBarPadding = 24.0;
const double _kSingleLineVerticalPadding = 14.0;
const Color _kSnackBackground = Color(0xFF323232);

// TODO(ianh): We should check if the given text and actions are going to fit on
// one line or not, and if they are, use the single-line layout, and if not, use
// the multiline layout. See link above.

// TODO(ianh): Implement the Tablet version of snackbar if we're "on a tablet".

const Duration _kSnackBarTransitionDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
const Duration _kSnackBarDisplayDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 4000);
const Curve _snackBarHeightCurve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;
const Curve _snackBarFadeCurve = Interval(0.72, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);

/// Specify how a [SnackBar] was closed.
///
/// The [ScaffoldState.showSnackBar] function returns a
/// [ScaffoldFeatureController]. The value of the controller's closed property
/// is a Future that resolves to a SnackBarClosedReason. Applications that need
/// to know how a snackbar was closed can use this value.
///
/// Example:
///
/// ```dart
/// Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
///   SnackBar( ... )
/// ).closed.then((SnackBarClosedReason reason) {
///    ...
/// });
/// ```

/// A button for a [SnackBar], known as an "action".
///
/// Snack bar actions are always enabled. If you want to disable a snack bar
/// action, simply don't include it in the snack bar.
///
/// Snack bar actions can only be pressed once. Subsequent presses are ignored.
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [SnackBar]
///  * <https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html>

class _SnackBarActionState extends State<SnackBarAction> {
  bool _haveTriggeredAction = false;

  void _handlePressed() {
    if (_haveTriggeredAction)
      return;
    setState(() {
      _haveTriggeredAction = true;
    });
    widget.onPressed();
    Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(reason: SnackBarClosedReason.action);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: _haveTriggeredAction ? null : _handlePressed,
      child: Text(widget.label),
      textColor: widget.textColor,
      disabledTextColor: widget.disabledTextColor,
    );
  }
}

/// A lightweight message with an optional action which briefly displays at the
/// bottom of the screen.
///
/// To display a snack bar, call `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar()`, passing
/// an instance of [SnackBar] that describes the message.
///
/// To control how long the [SnackBar] remains visible, specify a [duration].
///
/// A SnackBar with an action will not time out when TalkBack or VoiceOver are
/// enabled. This is controlled by [AccessibilityFeatures.accessibleNavigation].
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [Scaffold.of], to obtain the current [ScaffoldState], which manages the
///    display and animation of snack bars.
///  * [ScaffoldState.showSnackBar], which displays a [SnackBar].
///  * [ScaffoldState.removeCurrentSnackBar], which abruptly hides the currently
///    displayed snack bar, if any, and allows the next to be displayed.
///  * [SnackBarAction], which is used to specify an [action] button to show
///    on the snack bar.
///  * <https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html>
class MySnack extends StatelessWidget implements SnackBar {
  /// Creates a snack bar.
  ///
  /// The [content] argument must be non-null.
  const MySnack({
    Key key,
    @required this.content,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.action,
    this.duration = _kSnackBarDisplayDuration,
    this.animation,
  }) : assert(content != null),
        assert(duration != null),
        super(key: key);

  /// The primary content of the snack bar.
  ///
  /// Typically a [Text] widget.
  final Widget content;

  /// The Snackbar's background color. By default the color is dark grey.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// (optional) An action that the user can take based on the snack bar.
  ///
  /// For example, the snack bar might let the user undo the operation that
  /// prompted the snackbar. Snack bars can have at most one action.
  ///
  /// The action should not be "dismiss" or "cancel".
  final SnackBarAction action;

  /// The amount of time the snack bar should be displayed.
  ///
  /// Defaults to 4.0s.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [ScaffoldState.removeCurrentSnackBar], which abruptly hides the
  ///    currently displayed snack bar, if any, and allows the next to be
  ///    displayed.
  ///  * <https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html>
  final Duration duration;

  /// The animation driving the entrance and exit of the snack bar.
  final Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    assert(animation != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      accentColor: theme.accentColor,
      accentColorBrightness: theme.accentColorBrightness,
    );
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(width: _kSnackBarPadding),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: _kSingleLineVerticalPadding),
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: darkTheme.textTheme.subhead,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
    if (action != null) {
      children.add(ButtonTheme.bar(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _kSnackBarPadding),
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
        child: action,
      ));
    } else {
      children.add(const SizedBox(width: _kSnackBarPadding));
    }
    final CurvedAnimation heightAnimation = CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: _snackBarHeightCurve);
    final CurvedAnimation fadeAnimation = CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: _snackBarFadeCurve, reverseCurve: const Threshold(0.0));
    Widget snackbar = SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      top: false,
      child: Row(
        children: children,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      ),
    );
    snackbar = Semantics(
      container: true,
      liveRegion: true,
      onDismiss: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar(reason: SnackBarClosedReason.dismiss);
      },
      child: Dismissible(
        key: const Key('dismissible'),
        direction: DismissDirection.down,
        resizeDuration: null,
        onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
          Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar(reason: SnackBarClosedReason.swipe);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor ?? _kSnackBackground,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
            ),
            child: Material(
              elevation: 6.0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Theme(
                data: darkTheme,
                child: mediaQueryData.accessibleNavigation ? snackbar : FadeTransition(
                  opacity: fadeAnimation,
                  child: snackbar,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return ClipRect(
      child: mediaQueryData.accessibleNavigation ? snackbar : AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: heightAnimation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
            heightFactor: heightAnimation.value,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: snackbar,
      ),
    );
  }

  // API for Scaffold.addSnackBar():

  /// Creates an animation controller useful for driving a snack bar's entrance and exit animation.
  static AnimationController createAnimationController({ @required TickerProvider vsync }) {
    return AnimationController(
      duration: _kSnackBarTransitionDuration,
      debugLabel: 'SnackBar',
      vsync: vsync,
    );
  }

  /// Creates a copy of this snack bar but with the animation replaced with the given animation.
  ///
  /// If the original snack bar lacks a key, the newly created snack bar will
  /// use the given fallback key.
  SnackBar withAnimation(Animation<double> newAnimation, { Key fallbackKey }) {
    return MySnack(
      key: key ?? fallbackKey,
      content: content,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      action: action,
      duration: duration,
      animation: newAnimation,
    );
  }
}
````

**Changes made to SnackBar:**

- Renamed `SnackBar`to `MySnack`
- Added `implements SnackBar` to `MySnack` class
- Set `bottom: false` inside the `SafeArea` in `MySnack` build method
- Added a `Container` around the `Material` which is the background of the `SnackBar`
- Moved the `color` declaration from `Material` to the created `Container`
- Added the desired  `borderRadius` (together with the `color`) as a `BoxDecoration` to the `Container`

Comment: Thanks for the input Niklas, but your answer seems more difficult to approach to. However, I found the first answer the best one. You should also approach the same for future references. Thanks :)

Comment: The first answer definitely is the way to go :) Didn't know about the framework.

Comment: No problem Niklas, but thanks anyway for the input. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: is there a way to make the snacker from top of the screen instead of bottom

Comment: How can we add 2 pixels border on snackbar? Kindly suggest. Thanks.